# saber posição de uma tr (html <tr></tr>) na sequencia de tr's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, classificação

Tenho uma tela simples, onde já consegui fazer criar elementos dinamicamente, com o clique do botão, esses elementos são arrastáveis pra cima e pra baixo, e são dois elementos diferentes, um `textarea` e uma `img` que são adicionados dinamicamente.

[image: exemplo]

Queria colocar tipo um índice (em vermelho na imagem) em cada elemento que fosse adicionado, só que esse índice precisa ficar naquela posição exata sem mudar junto com os elementos, o que quero é vincular esse índice ao elemento que estiver na mesma linha dele, entendem?

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="button" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" id="add-row" value="Adicionar parágrafo" >   
    <input type="button" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" id="add-img" value="Adicionar imagem"    >  

    <table id="t1" class="example">

        <tr id="add-template-text">
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <img class="drag-handle" src="drag2.png" height="25" width="25" alt="click and drag to rearrange" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <!--<input id="tf1" type="text" value="I am in a table row!" /> -->
                <input type="hidden">
                <textarea class="tf" rows="2" cols="25"></textarea> 
            </td>
            <td>
                <img class="row-remover" src="remove.png" height="25" width="25" alt="Remove Row" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr id="add-template-img">
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <img class="drag-handle" src="drag2.png" height="25" width="25" alt="click and drag to rearrange" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <!--<input id="tf1" type="text" value="I am in a table row!" /> -->
                <input class="tf" type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img class="row-remover" src="remove.png" height="25" width="25" alt="Remove Row" />
            </td>
        </tr>  
    </table>    
</div>     





 /* 
 *  jquery.dynotable.js
 *  Created on Aug 1, 2011 3:36:39 PM by bob
 */
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        dynoTable: function(options) {

            var defaults = {
                removeClass: '.row-remover',
                cloneClass: '.row-cloner',
                addRowTemplateIdText: '#add-template-text',
                addRowTemplateIdImg: '#add-template-img',
                addRowButtonId: '#add-row',
                addRowButtonIdImg: '#add-img',
                lastRowRemovable: true,
                orderable: true,
                dragHandleClass: ".drag-handle",
                insertFadeSpeed: "slow",
                removeFadeSpeed: "fast",
                hideTableOnEmpty: true,
                onRowRemove: function(){},
                onRowClone: function(){},
                onRowAdd: function(){},
                onTableEmpty: function(){},
                onRowReorder: function(){}
            };     

            options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            var cloneRow = function(btn) {
                var clonedRow = $(btn).closest('tr').clone();  
                var tbod = $(btn).closest('tbody');
                insertRow(clonedRow, tbod); 
                options.onRowClone();
            }

            var insertRow = function(clonedRow, tbod) {                
                var numRows = $(tbod).children("tr").length;
                if(options.hideTableOnEmpty && numRows == 0) {
                    $(tbod).parents("table").first().show();
                }

                $(clonedRow).find('*').andSelf().filter('[id]').each( function() {
                    //change to something else so we don't have ids with the same name
                    this.id += '__c';
                });

                //finally append new row to end of table                           
                $(tbod).append( clonedRow );
                bindActions(clonedRow);
                $(tbod).children("tr:last").hide().fadeIn(options.insertFadeSpeed);
            }

            var removeRow = function(btn) {
                var tbod = $(btn).parents("tbody:first");
                var numRows = $(tbod).children("tr").length;

                if(numRows > 1 || options.lastRowRemovable === true) {
                    var trToRemove = $(btn).parents("tr:first");
                    $(trToRemove).fadeOut(options.removeFadeSpeed, function() {
                        $(trToRemove).remove();
                        options.onRowRemove();
                        if(numRows == 1) {                            
                            if(options.hideTableOnEmpty) {
                                $(tbod).parents('table').first().hide();
                            }
                            options.onTableEmpty();
                        }
                    });
                }                            
            }

            var bindClick = function(elem, fn) {
                $(elem).click(fn);                
            }                  

            var bindCloneLink = function(lnk) {
                bindClick(lnk, function(){                                
                    var btn = $(this);
                    cloneRow(btn); 
                    return false;
                });
            }

            var bindRemoveLink = function(lnk) {
                bindClick(lnk, function(){ 
                    var btn = $(this);
                    removeRow(btn);
                    return false;
                });
            }

            var bindActions = function(obj) {              
                obj.find(options.removeClass).each(function() {
                    bindRemoveLink($(this));
                });

                obj.find(options.cloneClass).each(function() {
                    bindCloneLink($(this));
                });
            }

            return this.each(function() {                             
                //Sanity check to make sure we are dealing with a single case
                if(this.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'table') {                                
                    var table = $(this);
                    var tbody = $(table).children("tbody").first();

                    if(options.orderable && jQuery().sortable) {                        
                        $(tbody).sortable({
                            handle : options.dragHandleClass,
                            helper:  function(e, ui) {
                                ui.children().each(function() {
                                    $(this).width($(this).width());
                                });
                                return ui;
                            },
                           // items: "tr",
                            update : function (event, ui) {
                                options.onRowReorder();
                            }
                        });
                    }                                 

                    $(table).find(options.addRowTemplateIdText).each(function(){
                        $(this).removeAttr("id");
                        var tmpl = $(this);
                        tmpl.remove();                        
                        bindClick($(options.addRowButtonId), function(){ 
                            var newTr = tmpl.clone();
                            insertRow(newTr, tbody);
                            options.onRowAdd();
                            return false;
                        });
                        //var contador = 0;
                        $('#add-row').on('click', function(){
                          // contador++; // somar +1
                           $('tr:last td:first-child').html($("#t1 tr").length);
                        });
                    });              

                    $(table).find(options.addRowTemplateIdImg).each(function(){
                        $(this).removeAttr("id");
                        var tmpl = $(this);
                        tmpl.remove();                                
                        bindClick($(options.addRowButtonIdImg), function(){ 
                            var newTr = tmpl.clone();
                            insertRow(newTr, tbody);
                            options.onRowAdd();
                            return false;
                        });
                       // var contador = 0;
                        $('#add-img').on('click', function(){
                            //contador++; // somar +1
                            //var contador = $("#t1 tr").length ;
                           $('tr:last td:first-child').html($("#t1 tr").length);
                        });
                    });                                
                    bindActions(table);

                    var numRows = $(tbody).children("tr").length;
                    if(options.hideTableOnEmpty && numRows == 0) {
                        $(table).hide();
                    }
                }                 
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[Aqui está o link](http://www.speedyshare.com/XEF4a/dyno-table.rar) com o que fiz até agora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para adicionar uma numeração em cada linha usando jQuery, você pode fazer algo assim:

```
$('#t1 tbody tr').each(function(index) {
    $(this).find('td:first').text(index + 1);
});
```

A primeira linha vai selecionar todas as linhas do corpo da tabela, excluindo cabeçalhos, se houver, através do seletor `#t1 tbody tr`.

Depois vai iterar sobre as linhas usando a função `each`, a qual passa à função *callback* o número do elemento.

Então, para cada elemento, ou linha neste caso, o trecho `find('td:first')` encontra a primeira célula e depois coloca o texto com a posição da linha mais um, pois vetores começam com zero em JavaScript.

Você vai precisar executar esse código no início da tabela e após mover uma linha ou qualquer evento que cause uma reordenação.

Comment: deu certo! obrigado!  coloqueis na hora de inserir, excluir e reordenar as linhas!